# Finding full folders list of a datastore

Tags: perl, sdk, vmware

I'm trying to get the entire folder name list of a VMWARE datastore (like folder1/folder2/datastore1, for example)

Found some code for a VM :

```
$vmtmp = Vim::find_entity_view(view_type => "VirtualMachine", filter => { name => $vm->name });
$path = Util::get_inventory_path($vmtmp ,Vim::get_vim());
```

but the find_entity_view function does not manage datastore data type.

Any clue to get this list (I'm newbie to perl sdk for vmware and a bit confused with the documentation) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`find_entity_view` in `Vim`](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/5e83c02a-0e6c-4bcc-9f0f-c545b230a0de/bf50706a-8886-43b6-acc2-2faf7954fb4f/doc/GUID-9A6D2E51-CCC1-4B82-B4B0-18C968CD2E73.html).

```
view_type => "Datastore"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. In my (too old ?) documentation, datastore was not present (tried dataStore, DataStore but not Datastore...).